# Mixing column names with built-in functions while using the Group BY cluase

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have constructed a relational database in SQLite to store coronavirus data of countries and regions around the world. The database schema is as follows:

- Country (Name, Population)
- DemographicData (CountryName*, AgeGroup, Gender, Cases, Deaths, Hospitalisations)
- CountryData (CountryName*, Date, DailyNewCases, DailyNewDeaths, CumulativeCases, CumulativeDeaths, 
  CumulativeRecoveries)
- Region (CountryName*, RegionName, Description)
- RegionData (RegionName*, Date, DailyNewCases, DailyNewDeaths, CumulativeCases, CumulativeDeaths, CumulativeRecoveries)

The primary keys are underlined. The foreign keys are denoted by asterisks (*).

I wrote the following code to display the number of deaths per million population by country:

```
SELECT CountryName, 
       MAX(CumulativeDeaths) AS ConfirmedDeaths,
       (ConfirmedDeaths*1000000/Population) AS DeathsPerMillion
FROM Country c
     INNER JOIN CountryData d ON (c.Name=d.CountryName)
GROUP BY d.CountryName
```

When I executed the query in SQLite, it returned the error message:"no such column:confirmed deaths". Why it returned such kind of error message? How can I fix this error to get what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct.  You cannot re-use a column alias in the same `select` where it is defined (nor in the `from` or `where`).

The calculation is simple.  So just repeat it:

```
SELECT CountryName, 
       MAX(CumulativeDeaths) AS ConfirmedDeaths,
       (MAX(CumulativeDeaths)*1000000/Population) AS DeathsPerMillion
FROM Country c INNER JOIN
     CountryData d
     ON c.Name = d.CountryName
GROUP BY d.CountryName, Population;
```

Note that you are referring to `Population` in the `SELECT` as well.  It should be part of the `GROUP BY`.  Or be the argument to an aggregation function (such as `MAX()` or `SUM()`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and the helpful tip "You cannot re-use a column alias in the same `SELECT` where it is defined (nor in the `FROM`)".